# Add context path to Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to set a Spring Boot applications context root programmatically. The reason for the context root is we want the app to be accessed from `localhost:port/{app_name}` and have all the controller paths append to it.

Here is the application configuration file for the web-app.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

  @Value("${mainstay.web.port:12378}")
  private String port;

  @Value("${mainstay.web.context:/mainstay}")
  private String context;

  private Set<ErrorPage> pageHandlers;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init(){
      pageHandlers = new HashSet<ErrorPage>();
      pageHandlers.add(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"/notfound.html"));
      pageHandlers.add(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,"/forbidden.html"));
  }

  @Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer(){
      TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
      logger.info("Setting custom configuration for Mainstay:");
      logger.info("Setting port to {}",port);
      logger.info("Setting context to {}",context);
      factory.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port));
      factory.setContextPath(context);
      factory.setErrorPages(pageHandlers);
      return factory;
  }

  public String getPort() {
      return port;
  }

  public void setPort(String port) {
      this.port = port;
  }
}
```

Here is the index controller for the main page.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String index(Model model){
      logger.info("Setting index page title to Mainstay - Web");
      model.addAttribute("title","Mainstay - Web");
      return "index";
  }

}
```

The new root of the application should be at `localhost:12378/mainstay`, but it is still located at `localhost:12378`.

What am I missing that is causing Spring Boot to not append the context root before the request mapping?

Comment: The video explains how to set context path in spring boot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HqtH3L9erE

Answer (score 479, accepted):

Why are you trying to roll your own solution. Spring-boot already supports that.

If you don't already have one, add an `application.properties` file to `src\main\resources`. In that properties file, add 2 properties:

```
server.contextPath=/mainstay
server.port=12378
```

**UPDATE (Spring Boot 2.0)**

As of Spring Boot 2.0 (due to the support of both Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux) the `contextPath` has been changed to the following:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/mainstay
```

You can then remove your configuration for the custom servlet container. If you need to do some post processing on the container you can add a `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` implementation to your configuration (for instance to add the error pages).

Basically the properties inside the `application.properties` serve as a default you can always override them by using another `application.properties` next to the artifact you deliver or by adding JVM parameters (`-Dserver.port=6666`).

See also [The Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html) especially the [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) section.

The class [`ServerProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java) implements the `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`. The default for `contextPath` is `""`. In your code sample you are setting the `contextPath` directly on the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`. Next the `ServerProperties` instance will process this instance and reset it from your path to `""`. ([This line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L110) does a `null` check but as the default is `""` it always fail and set the context to `""` and thus overriding yours).

Comment: Altough your answer is correct (I mean, you can customize the servlet container properties by the the application properties file), why is there a setContextPath(path) method, I mean, if the path is not enforced, what is it good for? BTW, same goes for the setContextPath(...) on the EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer

Comment: I would expect the one from `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` to also work. But I would go what is provided instead of trying to bolt on your own. Why your solution doesn't work has to do with the default behavior programmed (accidentally?) in the `ServerProperties`, the default configured `contextPath` is `""` (and it checks for `null` and not `""`. The latter overrides your explicitly set `contextPath`.

Comment: The properties have changed, see my answer below.

Comment: I guess the property in Spring Boot 2.0 is "server.servlet.context-path"

Comment: Maybe helpful for someone:  for context-path to work, spring boot project must be a web-project. <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> must be added as dependency

Comment: can we have an update on this answer for spring boot 3 @M.Deinum

Answer (score 42):

If you are using Spring Boot, then you don't have to configure the server properties via Bean initializing.

Instead, if one functionality is available for basic configuration, then it can be set in a "properties" file called `application`, which should reside under `src\main\resources` in your application structure. The "properties" file is available in two formats

1. `.yml`
2. `.properties`

The way you specify or set the configurations differs from one format to the other.

In your specific case, if you decide to use the extension `.properties`, then you would have a file called `application.properties` under `src\main\resources` with the following configuration settings

```
server.port = 8080
server.contextPath = /context-path
```

OTOH, if you decide to use the `.yml` extension (i.e. `application.yml`), you would need to set the configurations using the following format (i.e. `YAML`):

```
server:
    port: 8080
    contextPath: /context-path
```

For more common properties of Spring Boot refer to the link below:

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 29):

If you use Spring Boot 2.0.0 use:

```
server.servlet.context-path
```

Comment: this doesn't work for war files deployed in external tomcat

Comment: For me this didn't worked (Spring Boot 2.1.2), but did worked this: `server.servlet.contextPath=/api`

Comment: @pise, did you know how to fix it for war file in external tomcat?

Comment: @mohax if you deploy WAR file to external tomcat, you've to rename the WAR file to ROOT.war to make thing work as expected.

Comment: @DucLe in my case I just rename war file to needed path. I.e. `servicename#api`, where `#` is replaced by `/` by tomcat.

Comment: I wish they would stop changing the property name

Answer (score 15):

please note that the "server.context-path" or "server.servlet.context-path" [starting from springboot 2.0.x] properties will only work if you are deploying to an embedded container e.g., embedded tomcat. These properties will have no effect if you are deploying your application as a war to an external tomcat for example.

see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43856300/4449859

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to configure this when deploying to an external tomcat as `war` file using `springboot v2.x` and `tomcat v8.5`?

Comment: @abdel even I looking for the answer, what if we are deploying the war file in external tomcat how to set context path.

Comment: I was trying it out. It's exactly like what it was stated in the link above. Change the build -> finalName attribute value to your context path. The resulting war file will then be using the context path as the filename, which will then be used by tomcat to serve as the context path.

Comment: the only way i can think of for deploying as war in external tomcat is to ensure the war name matches the context you are after. so for example, if you want the context to be '/xyzwebapp' then your war must be named xyzwebapp.war. to achieve this, you can add the following to the <build> element in your pom.xml :         <finalName>xyzwebapp</finalName>.

Answer (score 11):

The correct properties are

```
server.servlet.path
```

to configure the path of the DispatcherServlet

and

```
server.servlet.context-path
```

to configure the path of the applications context below that.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using spring-boot-starter-webflux use:

```
spring:
  webflux:
    base-path: /api
```

I swear to God... I forget this every single time.

Comment: THIS! is what i needed for a spring boot 2.7.5 with spring-boot-starter-webflux but without spring-boot-starter-web

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by adding the port and contextpath easily to add the configuration in [src\main\resources] .properties file and also .yml file

application.porperties file configuration

```
server.port = 8084
server.contextPath = /context-path
```

application.yml file configuration

```
server:
port: 8084
contextPath: /context-path
```

We can also change it programmatically in spring boot.

```
@Component
public class ServerPortCustomizer implements     WebServerFactoryCustomizer<EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer > {

@Override
public void customize(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer factory) {
    factory.setContextPath("/context-path");
    factory.setPort(8084);
}
```

}

We can also add an other way

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {SpringApplication application =     new pringApplication(MyApplication.class);
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("server.servlet.context-path", "/context-path");
    map.put("server.port", "808");
    application.setDefaultProperties(map);
    application.run(args);
    }       
}
```

using java command spring boot 1.X

```
java -jar my-app.jar --server.contextPath=/spring-boot-app     --server.port=8585
```

using java command spring boot 2.X

```
java -jar my-app.jar --server.servlet.context-path=/spring-boot-app --server.port=8585
```

Comment: we can also add the server port programatically

Answer (score 5):

If you are using application.yml and spring version above 2.0 then configure in the below manner.

```
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
     context-path: /demo-api
```

Now all the API call will be like http://localhost:8081/demo-api/

Comment: This is worked for me. thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

We can change context root path using a simple entry in the properties file.

`application.properties`

```
### Spring boot 1.x #########
server.contextPath=/ClientApp

### Spring boot 2.x #########
server.servlet.context-path=/ClientApp
```

Answer (score 2):

For below Spring boot 2 version you need to use below code

```
server:
   context-path: abc
```

And For Spring boot 2+ version use below code

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: abc
```

Answer (score 1):

We can set it in the `application.properties` as
`API_CONTEXT_ROOT=/therootpath`

And we access it in the Java class as mentioned below

```
@Value("${API_CONTEXT_ROOT}")
private String contextRoot;
```

Answer (score 1):

**server.contextPath=/mainstay**

works for me if i had one war file in JBOSS. Among multiple war files where each contain jboss-web.xml it didn't work. I had to put jboss-web.xml inside WEB-INF directory with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>mainstay</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: It's not working with Wildfly23. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot 1.5:

Add the following property in `application.properties`:

```
server.context-path=/demo
```

Note: `/demo` is your context path URL.

Answer (score 1):

We can set it using `WebServerFactoryCustomizer`. This can be added directly in the spring boot main method class which starts up the Spring ApplicationContext.

```
@Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory>
      webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/demo");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring Boot 2.x and want to pass the context path property in the command line, you should put double // like this:

```
--server.servlet.context-path=//your-path
```

That worked for me running in windows.

Answer (score 1):

It must be:
server.servlet.context-path = / demo
note that it does not have quotes only the value preceded by '/'
this value goes in your application.properties file

Answer (score 1):

You can use in Spring Boot: 2.1.6 like below:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api-path
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can add this property to spring property file**

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/your_path
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works. With SpringBoot 3.0, this works:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/users
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Server port-->

server.port=8080

<!--Context Path of the Application-->

server.servlet.context-path=/ems
```

Comment: Server port will be 8080. if you want any other port, you can replace 8080. Fro application context path i have set ems. You can set other path as per your requirement

Comment: That's useful information, why don't  you add it into your answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I can see many outdated answers / context-path formats.
Please use latest ones.

application.yml

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /hello-context-path
```

application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/hello-context-path
```

Answer (score -1):

context path can be directly integrated to the code but it is not advisable since it cannot be reused so write in the application.properties file
server.contextPath=/name of the folder where you placed the code
contextPath = name of the folder where you placed the code/
Note:watch the slash carefully.