# Spring Data Rest base path

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have added Spring Data Rest (2.0) to an existing Spring MVC application by creating a Java config class that extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration, and adding @RestResource to the repositories.

Is it possible to change the base URL for the Rest API? E.g:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/customers
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/customers
```

I tried to override configureRepositoryRestConfiguration using setBaseURI, but it didn't seem to apply to all links in the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding a second "AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer":

```java
public class RestWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/rest/*" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServletName() {
        return "rest-exporter";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also configure it via web.xml too right ? using `RepositoryRestDispatcherSerlvet` or `RepositoryRestExporterServlet`. is there any need of using Java configuration if u r already using web.xml ?

Answer (score 31):

As of [Spring Boot 1.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) you are able to set this property:

`spring.data.rest.baseUri=api`

Alternatively:

`spring.data.rest.base-uri=api`

(Spring Boot uses a [relaxed binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) system)

**NOTE:** I have found that if you have extended `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` with custom configuration, the property does not take effect. For more information see:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392

Once the next version of Spring Boot is released (after 1.2.1), the solution will be to extend `RepositoryRestMvcBootConfiguration` instead.

Comment: From your referenced doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html# DATA RESET (RepositoryRestConfiguration})
spring.data.rest.base-uri= # base URI against which the exporter should calculate its links

Comment: @adam0404 - both work, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding

Comment: In Spring Boot 1.2.3, baseUri is deprecated. Use basePath (or base-path) instead.

Comment: In my case (Spring Boot 2.3.2) the property `spring.data.rest.base-path` was being ignored. Turns out I had a `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` in my code base (from before switching from Spring to Spring Boot). After deleting that class, the property worked like expected.

Answer (score 16):

You can configure the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` by overriding it in the following manner:

```java
@Configuration
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class RestDataConfig  extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
    try {
      config.setBaseUri(new URI("/data"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This changes the base uri for the links only.

Comment: @EthanAnderson that's right. Wouldn't it (arguably) suffice in the case of a fairly simple application?

Comment: From what I can tell it's no help at all since you'll end up with links pointing to controller endpoints which do not exist.

The resource will be accessible off of /resource, but the links to said resource will appear as /data/resource and you will likely get a 404 following a link.

Comment: On further inspection it looks like the logic changed recently. In my project running SDR 2.0.2.RELEASE it just changes the links, but in 2.1.0.RELEASE it appears to pass in the baseUri() when instantiating the relevant beans.

Comment: `URI.create("/data")` is helpful to avoid having to catch the checked exception (throws runtime instead)

Comment: I do not think you need @Import since you are extending it

Answer (score 16):

I used spring boot 1.2.3.REALEASE
I tried `spring.data.rest.baseUri=/api` and `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api` but it not working.

After try and googling: `server.servlet-path=/api` worked for me.

Comment: Your config works for me with Spring Boot 1.5.4.  However, I have problems with spring security. So I solve the issue this way (with yml syntax):
"spring:  
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: api"

Answer (score 8):

Add to following line to application.properties(Spring boot version 2.2.0.M2)

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/rest
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Look at official documentation [how to change rest base uri](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri)

But I don't know why for me `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api` property is not working and I must wrote second solution:

```
@Configuration
class CustomRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {

    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setBasePath("/api");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to `use spring.data.rest.base-path` instead of `spring.data.rest.basePath`

Answer (score 1):

You set the property, e.g. in your YAML file:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/rest
```

Answer (score 0):

See official documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

```
server.servlet-path=/ # Path of the main dispatcher servlet.
server.context-path=
```

you can include it on the configuration file.

See also [Add context path to Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/spring-boot-context-root)