# Spring Boot Starter Data Rest change URL of repository from the root URI

Tags: rest, spring-boot

Following the spring.io example here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/ for exposing a repository as a rest web service works just fine, but I cannot see how to change the URL of the exposed service. The API documentation is a little vague as to what the annotation parameters mean, perhaps some prior knowledge is assumed.

What I want - A HATEOAS service accessed at `http://localhost:8080/api/people` for a People repository. I want to achieve this URL using annotations only, not messing with the context root or similar. I tried the following repository annotations:

- `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "api/people", path = "people")`
- `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "api/people")`
- `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "api/people", path = "api/people")`

None of these work.

I know I have probably missed the obvious, much appreciate anyone who can point it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Data Rest base path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024716/spring-data-rest-base-path)

Comment: in your application.properties:

    spring.data.rest.base-path=/api

source:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri

Answer (score 9):

As of [Spring Boot 1.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) you are able to set this property:

`spring.data.rest.baseUri=api`

Alternatively:

`spring.data.rest.base-uri=api`

(Spring Boot uses a [relaxed binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) system)

**NOTE:** I have found that if you have extended `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` with custom configuration, the property does not take effect. For more information see:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392

Once the next version of Spring Boot is released (after 1.2.1), the solution will be to extend `RepositoryRestMvcBootConfiguration` instead.

Comment: Is there any real advantage to setting this in a property vs in your class that extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration ?

Comment: It's a bit cleaner and Springy since you probably have an applications property file anyway. Doing it in code is more typing and more code that should be tested. Relying on the spring convention means you don't need to test your own code or have a different property. Lastly, it makes on boarding new developers easier, since it's a standard convention instead of custom code. For this property itself it's probably not a big deal, but it's the principle of it

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

It's spring.data.rest.base-uri

Comment: @adam0404 - either will work according to Spring Boot's property loader.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Boot 1.4.3 the code should be :

```
spring.data.rest.base-path:api
```

(I think baseUri is deprecated since 1.2.3)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in case you haven't read it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't change the base path of the REST services using the annotation `@RepositoryRestResource` combined with a `CrudRepository`, I managed to do it using a `JpaRepository` and a custom controller with the annotation `@RequestMapping`.

The repository could be something like:

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepository : JpaRepository<Person, Long>
```

And the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/people")
class PersonRestController(private val personRepository: PersonRepository) {
    ...
```

On the other hand, you can change the base path of all your REST services modifying it in the **application.properties** file of your project. Add the lines:

```
# DATA REST (RepositoryRestConfiguration)
spring.data.rest.base-path = api
```

Change `api` with the path you wish you use in your URLs. The first line is a comment and, as so, it's not mandatory, but is useful to mark the nature of the configuration value for future references.

You can find all the common application properties of Spring Boot 2.0.1 in the [Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) of the documentation.