# How to specify prefix for all controllers in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have controller mappings to `/user` and `/order`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    ...
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {
    ...
}
```

I want to access these by URL at `http://localhost:8080/api/users`  and `http://localhost:8080/api/orders`, respectively.

How do I achieve this in Spring Boot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Context Root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/spring-boot-context-root)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can provide a mapping to root context path of your spring boot application to `/api/*` in your custom configuration.

```js
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@Configuration
public class DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet(), "/api/");
        registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

or add this to your `application.properties` in `src\main\resources` folder

```
server.contextPath=/api
```

**EDIT**

[As of Spring Boot 2.x the property has been deprecated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#servlet-specific-server-properties) and should be replaced with

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/api
```

More you find here [Spring Boot Context Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/spring-boot-context-root) and here [Add servlet mapping to DispatcherServlet](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/011-add-servlet-mapping-to-dispatcherservlet-spring-boot/)

Comment: this adds the prefix to everything, not just the controllers

Comment: Both work great when wanting to add a context path. The two issues that I faced was that creating a DispatcherServelt bean also meant that the /oauth routes were under the context path which falls outside of RESTful standards; and using contextPath in the configuration introduced the same issue as well as CORS and tests not being aware of the context path at all. I ended up adding the @RequestMapping annotation to each controller as necessary.

Comment: It should just be "server.contextPath=/api/" . Having a trailing * is causing error in Spring Boot version 1.3.5

Comment: "server.context-path=/api/" works for me. Many Thanks!

Comment: Please note, org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean was deprecated in 1.4 and its replacement, org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean, was introduced. The deprecated class was removed in 1.5

Comment: Note that for spring 2.0 it is server.servlet.contextPath: /xxx

Comment: Is this working for Spring Boot 2.0? It doesn't seem to.

Comment: The `server.servlet.context-path = /api/*` sitting in the `application.properties` file was giving me the `Error registering Tomcat:type=TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader,host=localhost,context=/api/* - ContextPath must start with '/' and not end with '/'` error. The `server.servlet.context-path = /api` property without quotes was the one required for the application to start.

Comment: For Spring Boot 2.0 it must be like `server.servlet.context-path=/api`.

Answer (score 64):

If you want to add prefix just for some controllers I found two others solutions

#### Option 1 - Use spring SpEL to add a prefix variable for your controllers

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "${v1API}/users")
public class V1FruitsController {

    @GetMapping(path = "")
    @ResponseBody
    public String list(){
        return "[\"Joe\", \"Peter\"]";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
v1API=/api/v1
```

#### Option 2 - Create a custom controller annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public @interface V1APIController {
    @AliasFor(annotation = Component.class)
    String value() default "";
}


@V1APIController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    @ReponseBody
    public String index(){
        return "[\"Joe\", \"Peter\"]";
    }
}
```

then test it

```
curl -X GET localhost:8080/api/v1/users
```

Comment: Yes, but what if you have a lot of methods in your UserController?  Now you have traded off writing @RequestMapping("/api/users") at the class level for prefixing every method's RequestMapping with "users".

Comment: Is there a reason why you used @Component for the annotation and alias and not @RestController?

Comment: @JimBob no, you can ue `@RestController` as well

Answer (score 22):

If you are using spring boot 2 (spring framework 5), there is a replacement of the property in your `application.properties`:

```
server.contextPath
```

for:

```
server.servlet.context-path=
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to add '/api'  prefix and added by server.servlet.context-path=/api

Answer (score 13):

Add your default path in the `application.properties` as:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/mainPath
```

Here `/mainPath` will be the prefix for all the controller

Comment: On my current version spring boot, that property name is  context-path.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the other comments about changing the application property for the context path, you can also use an application property to set the prefix for the dispatcher servlet alone, in Spring Boot 2.3.1.

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api
```

The request mappings would not change in your controllers. While context path moves the entire application to a different path, servlet path only limits the URLs that are handled by the dispatcher servlet. The servlet path is the equivalent of the servlet mapping in web.xml. Other resources that do not use
the dispatcher servlet can be accessed from any other URL.

If you have other controllers that are not mapped to the `/api` prefix, then this will not work, unless you declare a second dispatcher servlet with a different prefix for those controllers.

Answer (score 7):

Since **spring-webmvc-5.1.x**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerTypePredicate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix("/api",
                HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(RestController.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed! Only for classes which are annotated with @RestController. This allows me to separate between a webjar frontend and the api.

Answer (score 4):

In application.yml add this:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: "/contextPath"
```

Answer (score 3):

For those interested, here is a Kotlin take on [deFreitas' Option 2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182494/671896) as I was unable to use `spring.data.rest.basePath` or `server.servlet.contextPath` in `application.yaml`. (This is with Spring Boot 2.1.2 and Kotlin 1.13.11)

```
package com.myproject.controller

import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping

import kotlin.annotation.MustBeDocumented
import kotlin.annotation.Retention
import kotlin.annotation.Target
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationRetention

@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.FILE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
@Component
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
annotation class V1ApiController(
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = Component::class)
    val value: String = ""
)
```

If you're using IntelliJ, optimizing imports will probably remove the Kotlin annotation imports for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Add this at **application.properties**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api/v1/
```

Answer (score 1):

`server.servlet.context-path` is the correct path.  Not `server.servlet.contextPath`, and unfortunately it doesn't seem to support lists which you could do in web.xml like this:

```
    <servlet>
        <description>Servlet used by Spring MVC to handle all requests into the application</description>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Exactly! This should support a list, like the old configurations with web.xml. I didn't find it, but there must be some way, right?

Answer (score 0):

Additional. If you use `.yaml`, you could write it as:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /api
```