# Spring boot static content for nested / prefixed controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot 2.0.2 and Freemarker for my web application. The static content of my webapp fails to load for nested / prefixed controllers.

All of the static content (images, CSS, js) is under

```
/src/main/resources/static/js
/src/main/resources/static/images
/src/main/resources/static/css
```

Everything works great if I use this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userProfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getUser(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelAndView model,@RequestParam("userId") String userId) {

    UserProfile userProfile = userService.findById(userId);
    model.addObject("userProfile", userProfile);
    model.setViewName("userDetails");
    return model;
}

  userDetails.ftl is located at /src/main/resources/templates/userDetails.ftl
```

However, I'm seeing 404 on the static content (js/css/images) for this controller while making a GET request from the browser.

```
https://localhost:8443/users/js/saveUser.js -- 404
(Please note "users" in the URL while trying to load static content)

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getUser(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelAndView model,@RequestParam("userId") String userId) {

    UserProfile userProfile = userService.findById(userId);
    model.addObject("userProfile", userProfile);
    model.setViewName("userDetails");
    return model;
}
```

**Code of the view**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/homepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/user-profile-display.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/saveUser.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/authenticate.js}"></script>
```

I've looked at the following issues but can't find a solution that would work:

[How to specify prefix for all controllers in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006501/how-to-specify-prefix-for-all-controllers-in-spring-boot)

[spring boot: separate REST from static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940856/spring-boot-separate-rest-from-static-content)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's probably because you're using an incorrect relative path to the static resources in your view. Post the relevant code.

Comment: @JBNizet - I've added the entire code for the controller. Please let me know if you need additional info

Comment: The problem, as I said, is most probably that you're using an incorrect relative path to the static resources **in your view**. So, post the relevant code: the code **of the view**, where you're linking to static resources

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Updated @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using relative paths.

So, if the current URL, dsplayed in the address bar of your browser, is `http://somehost/userProfile`, the relative path `css/homepage.css` is resolved relative to `http://somehost/`, and the request is thus sent to `http://somehost/css/homepage.css`, which works fine

If the current URL, dsplayed in the address bar of your browser, is `http://somehost/user/profile`, the relative path `css/homepage.css` is resolved relative to `http://somehost/user/`, and the request is thus sent to `http://somehost/user/css/homepage.css` which doesn't work, since that's not the URL of the CSS resource.

Use absolute paths:

```
href="/css/homepage.css"
```

This basically works like paths on your hard drive. If you're in the director `/home/tim` and execute `less foo.txt`, it will display the file `/home/tim/foo.txt`. If you execute `less /foo.txt`, it will display the file `/foo.txt`.