# Spring Boot - static content at root level while using a context-path

Tags: java, spring

let's say I have a application.yml with this content

```
server:
  port: 8000
  context-path: /rest
```

so, all controllers and html will be accessed like this
http://server:8000/rest/controller

so, having this configuration...

it is possible to add some static html element to its root level without changing its context-path? (I added a index.html to static folder already).

in other words:

having that application.yml, I need to retrieve a empty html when accessing to our app root-level

http://server:8000

but, currently, I can only access that html on this url

http://server:8000/rest

any ideas? 
thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
i'm doing this because our load balancer, when accessing http://server:8000 will get a 404 from spring-boot, thus marking our server/app as non-accessible.

since from springboot, I have control over tomcat. is there any way I could add a basic html to its root level so our load balancer does not mark our application as unavailable? 
pd: I have no access to setup that load balancer :(

Comment: You could use `/` as context path for your application and prefix all controller's `@RequestMapping`s with `/rest`.

Comment: I know, but that does not sound like a good approach. in fact, we have a lot of controllers and that approach seems a bit of an overkill :(

Comment: This question was asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006501/how-to-specify-prefix-for-all-controllers-in-spring-boot before, but has no satisfying answers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context-path` affects the entire application. In Tomcat or other servlet container it's used to distinguish between multiple WARs deployed to the same servlet container e.g. `http://localhost:8000/abc` and `http://localhost:8000/xyz`.

Since you are using Spring Boot you are most likely packaging the servlet container with your application. In this case set `server.context-path = /` and use `@RestController("/rest")` to expose the REST API as `http://localhost:8000/rest`.

Comment: I'm afraid I might have to do that. but, is there no other way? I want to believe~~

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller with `@RequestMapping("/")` which will return view name but for this requires any view configuration.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "springbootexampleindex";
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, given its context-path, it will be accessible from http://server:8000/rest only

Answer (score 0):

You could not add a context path, but add a custom J2EE or spring filter. anything request with "/rest/" in the path, send it to the controllers as a forward after removing the "rest/" portion. Anything without /rest/ dont filter it - let the request continue as is, so spring will serve static content as is. This serve your static from root and your APIs appear to be as under /rest/