# Custom anotaion for ApiController to prefix /api not working Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have defined an ApiController to add a prefix (/api) to route match. I am using Spring Boot

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public @interface ApiController {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value();

}
```

and Use in the controller like

```
@ApiController("/user")
public class UserController {

    /**
     * Define url methods
     *
     */
}
```

but I don't know why /api/user/ not serving. it serve at /user/ Endpoint. Can any one know the exact error ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `@AliasFor`, it means that the property of your annotation is an alias for the property from another annotation. In your example, `ApiController.value` is an alias for `RequestMapping.value` and when you set `ApiController.value`, the same value set to `RequestMapping.value`. Not adding or concatenating, just set the new value. You can read how `@AliasFor` work [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html)

What about your issue. As I understand you want to set api root url. You can do it with one of the way from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006501/how-to-specify-prefix-for-all-controllers-in-spring-boot). Please note that in **Option 2**, the same technic is used, but there is not used `@AliasFor` for overriding/extending `RequestMapping.value`.

Comment: Actually I have tried many including the Option 2 from your suggestion but nothing fruitful. Although, thanks for your help.

Comment: It's strange. Could you what doesn't work in **Option 2**?

Answer (score 1):

I am explaining below, How I solve the problem after checking the Implementation of @RestController.

I create a Alias for RestController as

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RestController
public @interface ApiController {

    @AliasFor(
            annotation = RestController.class
    )
    String value() default "";
}
```

and then I create a configuration to add the prefix.

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix("/api", HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(ApiController.class));
    }
}
```

and its works for me.