# Unable to post the photo in postman - No Message Available, Error 404 in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling, postman

I am using sts to write my code and here is the problem now when I try to post the photo/attachments I am receiving the error 404 in postman and whitelabel error in browser

**Below is the code snippet from controller class, for photo attachment**

```java
@POST
@Path("/{id}/photo")
public Response updatePhoto(@PathParam("id") String id, @FormDataParam("photo") InputStream is) throws RecordNotFoundException {
    boolean updated = sanService.updatePhoto(id, is);
    if (updated)
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("").build();
    else
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_MODIFIED).entity("").build();
}
```

**This is the variable from model class**

```java
@Id
private String id;
private String attachments;
```

**Below is the error i am receiving in postman when i am hitting the path to post the photo**

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-04-03T17:10:10.105+0000",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/upload"
}
```

**This is the url i am hitting to post the attachment in postman as well as in browser**

```
http://localhost:8082/5e845cea6cdb4531f30023ab/photo
```

Please assist or advice how can I proceed

Comment: What is the path to the controller?

Comment: projectname/src/controller package/controller class

Comment: What I meant was something similar the question in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006501/how-to-specify-prefix-for-all-controllers-in-spring-boot) post. Notice the `@RequestMapping("/users")` on top of the controller. It might be that in your case either that is missing from the setup of the controller or else, it is missing in the URL you are trying to hit.

Comment: /sourcing/src/main/java/com/san/controller/SANcontroller.java this is the controller path

Comment: no I did not used @requestmapping annotation

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure you have your controller class annotated correctly with `@RestController` annotation.
2. Please check if you have annotated your controller class with something like `@RequestMapping("/foo")`. In that case you need to define this request path: `/foo/{id}/photo`
3. Your controller method can be annotations can be written a bit cleaner. Instead of those two annotations you can use this: `@PostMapping("/{id}/photo")`

Comment: yeah I have checked all this step...but still the issue is the same

Comment: Are you maybe setting context-path in your yaml configuration? If you are, that needs to prefixed as well to your path

Comment: Hi GoranLegenda, please find the yaml content below

server.port=8082
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=sanservice
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username= san@gmail.com
spring.mail.password= san
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true