# How to make custom request mapping annotation with spring to add prefixes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Using spring boot 2 on java 11, I want to make a custom annotation for each REST API version (eg: "/api/v1/") that can be joined with subsequent URI components as below:

```java
@APIv1("/users/")    // this annotation should prepend "/api/v1/{argument}"
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/info")
    public String info() {return "This should be returned at /api/v1/users/info/";}

    /* More methods with mappings */
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to define that @APIv1 annotation.
From what I've searched, I referenced [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182494/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) to write the following:

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@interface APIv1 {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RestController.class)
    String value() default "";
}
```

But this cannot handle arguments. Doing the same as above will route to `/api/v1/info/` whether the argument is given or not. It's better than nothing since I can switch the method annotation to `@GetMapping("/users/info")`, but I was wondering if there was a way to combine the constant with an argument to reduce repetition across method annotations within the same controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around with different solutions proposed in similar questions, I settled on using my custom annotation to hold the prefix path separately and join them in WebMvcConfigurer

Usage in controllers:

```
@APIv1("/users")
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/info")
    public String info() {return "This should be returned at /api/v1/users/info/";}

    /* More methods with mappings */
}
```

where the custom annotations are defined as follows (in a separate package, ie: com.example.myannotations):

```
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PrefixMapping {
    /**
     * The prefix to prepend to path mappings
     * */
    String value() default "";
}
```

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@PrefixMapping("/api/v1")    // Prefix to add when using this annotation
public @interface APIv1 {
    /**
     * Alias for {@link RequestMapping#value}.
     */
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String value() default "";
}
```

And define a WebMvcConfigurer that will search for annotations on startup

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false) {
            @Override
            protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(PrefixMapping.class));

        String pkgName = "com.example.myannotations";    // Package name where the custom annotations are defined in
        provider.findCandidateComponents(pkgName).forEach(bean -> {
            try {
                String className = bean.getBeanClassName();
                Class<? extends Annotation> clz = (Class<? extends Annotation>) Class.forName(className);

                String prefix = clz.getDeclaredAnnotation(PrefixMapping.class).value();
                configurer.addPathPrefix(prefix, HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(clz));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | ClassCastException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now if I want an annotation with different prefix, I can define the annotation without changing anything else.

One thing that troubled me when writing the `WebConfig` class was getting the `Class` object for the annotation class from the `BeanDefinition` returned by `findCandidateComponents(pkgName)` even though there were supposed to be functions for getting them available.

```
Functions I tried                                       -> resulting Class<?>::getName() or null

- ClassUtils.getUserClass(bean.getClass())              -> org.springframework.context.annotation.ScannedGenericBeanDefinition
- AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean.getClass())              -> java.lang.Class    - ScannedGenericBeanDefinition if bean instead of bean.class()
- AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(bean.getClass())    -> java.lang.Class    - ScannedGenericBeanDefinition if bean instead of bean.class()
- AopProxyUtils.proxiedUserInterfaces(bean.getClass())  -> [java.io.Serializable, java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement]    - [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition] if bean instead of bean.getClass()
- bean.getResolvableType().resolve()                    -> null
- bean.getResolvableType().toClass()                    -> java.lang.Object
- bean.getResolvableType().getRawClass()                -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

In `@APIv1` you defined:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
```

So it is working as you told it to.

Comment: Yes, that's the best I was able to get so far, but I was wondering if there was a different way so that I can concatenate it with the argument given to my custom annotation. Both are compile-time constant string literals so I thought there might be a way