# Change root URL in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, url, model-view-controller

I am trying to change my Spring MVC project's root URL to '/' instead of '/springmvc' by default.

For example, I want the root url (which is mapped to @RequestParam('/')) to be http://localhost:8080/ instead of http://localhost:8080/springmvc

How could I do this? Thank you!

Comment: How and where are you running this application?

Comment: If this is a traditional spring application, packaged in a war then it's up the to servlet container to specify the root url for the application. You can always force an application to be served from the root, but it's going to be done differently depending on whether you are using tomcat, jetty, etc.

Comment: im running it on Tomcat in Eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application)

Comment: i'll look into this.. thanks Rob, I have been searching for 30 mins but couldn't find the correct thread

Comment: You can try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application