# Rest path for application

Tags: rest, path, spring-boot, request-mapping

I'm fairly new to Spring Boot, but I want to want to build my application in such a way, that can deploy mulitple applications on the same server and i want to distinguish the applications in the rest path.

For example, say i have the applications user-management and animal-management and i have a rest-controller in both of them responding to the path `\names`.
Both those applications run on `localhost:8080` so when sending a `GET` to `localhost:8080/users/names`, I want the controller of the user-management to react and the same for animal with a `GET` to `localhost:8080/animals/names`.

I can put a `@RequestMapping` on the controller to acchieve the `names` part, but if i do the same on the application, it gets ignored.

Basically I want to tell my application "Every controller in this application should be mapped to the rest path specified on the controller, but prefixed with 'x'".

How can I do that.

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/spring-boot-context-root

Comment: You have different spring boot applications listening to the same port?

Comment: @AliDehghani no, I don't. I just didn't know better how to explain the application contextPath.

Comment: Thanks to @Vaionixx I know know what it is and it's exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the contextPath, I just didn't know the name.
By putting the `server.contextPath=/users` attribute in the application.properies it worked like i wanted to.
Thank you @Vaionixx