# Spring Boot - Why it does not consider project name as context for the dispatcher servlet mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Just like Spring MVC when we used deploy the application in the servlet container it is used to pickup the project name as servlet context and then as per our servlet mapping the container will process the request.

Here my question is i created spring-boot rest application having crud operations and deployed in tomcat server. But when i try to access any url like [http://localhost:8080/findAllRecords] then the server return 404 error request url not found but i add extra / in the url[http://localhost:8080//findAllRecords] it successfully execute the request.

Comment: are you using SpringBoot embedded tom cat?

Comment: What does your @Controller look like?

Comment: @Hareesh; thanks for you reply...sorry for late comment...yes i am using embedded tomcat...

Comment: @Macro: I am using RestController here

Comment: Can post your server.* of the application.properties file

Comment: @Hareesh: <br/> In my application properties having only jdbc connection properties.

Comment: @Hareesh: I do not have any configuration in my properties other than connection properties....

Comment: @Hareesh: Thank you for suggestion for the properties file.I google the same thing and find the solution and resolve this problem by adding<br/> server.port = 8080<br/>
server.contextPath = /contectPath <br/>http://stackoverflow.com/a/35294685/3286239(This post help to sort out my problem)......