# Swagger2 Change Base Path for Swagger Ui

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

Was able to setup Swagger 2 to my SpringBoot app by just adding this SwaggerConfig file and adding the following dependencies:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error"))).build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("Motorcycle Shop - Restful Services", "Rest based API for Motorcycle Shop", "1.0", "",
                new Contact("", "", ""), "", "");
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Despite fact that my controller class looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/motorcycles")
public class ProductController { 

// GET method

}
```

... am still able to invoke that controller by doing this:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/motorcycles
```

I have to open up the Swagger-ui.html file using the following URL path:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

How can I make my Spring Boot app to show something like this (the actual app name or the default RequestMapping specified in a controller - if the controller is the only one in the app):

```
http://localhost:8080/motorcycles/swagger-ui.html
```

Basically, how can I prefix the swagger-ui.html with the app name?

So, lets say my app is called motorboy, this is what I want:

```
http://localhost:8080/motorboy/swagger-ui.html
```

And the Curl -X GET for the REST Endpoint looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/motorboy/motorcycles
```

It seems that spring-boot is just using plain old http://localhost:8080 for the default app name in the browser for swagger.

Comment: If you just want to set a context path for your Spring Boot application maybe take a look at the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418450/5871191 the @RequestMapping("/motorcycles") only applies to the ProductController.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem setting context path to spring boot application in the `application.properties` (you can set this variable with different ways, see [this spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)):

`server.servlet.context-path=/user` (or motorboy in your case)

After set context path I can access swagger-ui or swagger docs from `http://localhost:8080/user/swagger-ui.html` and `http://localhost:8080/user/v2/api-docs` respectively.

If you want I can make a simple project and update to github just for clarify and explain this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution/workaround that helps to define the base path for swagger.

```
@Component
@Primary
public class CustomBasePathJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer {

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "/my-base-path";

    public CustomBasePathJsonSerializer(List<JacksonModuleRegistrar> modules) {
        super(modules);
    }

    @Override
    public Json toJson(Object toSerialize) {
        if (toSerialize instanceof Swagger) {
            Swagger swagger = (Swagger) toSerialize;
            swagger.basePath(BASE_PATH);
        }
        return super.toJson(toSerialize);
    }
}
```