# How to set root url in the spring boot with apache tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have springboot application than will be deployed to the tomcat.
I have class:

```
public class SpringBootApp    extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {
....
}
```

In the application.properties I have:

```
server.contextPath=/
```

But when app going deployed to the tomcat, it not unavailable with url like:
http://193.123.33.33:8080/
Buy available with url http://193.123.33.33:8080/appname

How I will setting up springboot for root url mapping in the tomcat?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add context path to Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application)

Comment: This is your Tomcat that you need to set up to redirect on your base url, and not your spring boot app. Your app is appname, and you can't go above it. So you need to point all the incoming calls on the URL http://193.123.33.33:8080/ to the URL http://193.123.33.33:8080/appname

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza Martin exactly looking to do the opposite

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I need analog like web.xml: <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> Do spring boot any setting like this? I don't know:(

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza Path to DispatcherServlet of the SpringBoot.

Comment: @DamCx redirect is bad solution. I think..

Comment: That is the only way, in fact. Unless you build an apache as a front to redirect on the right URL, but this may be too much for your need

Comment: @DamCx Solution is create ROOT.war in the webapp tomcat folder.

Answer (score 0):

in configuration file ".yml" file need to declare

server:
  port: 8089
  display-name: displayname

and for the domain name need to configure in tomcat properties. but for the local environment http:// will not work.

Comment: Do you have a sample of this yml file?

Comment: server:
  port: 2222


management:
  security:
    enabled: false


mail:
  enabled: false
  smtp:
    host: 
    port:
  fromAddress: 
  fromName: 
  success:
    recipients: 
  failed:
    recipients: 

---
spring:
  profiles: 
logging:
 config: 
server:
  ssl:
    key-alias: 
    key-password: 
    key-store: 
    key-store-provider: 
    key-store-type:

Comment: Format of .yml file is very important , if you miss any tab of space then it will not work.

Comment: *.properties is analog *.yml files and i have this settings. Or your yml settings successfully appled and work in the tomcat with root url path?

Comment: I am not sure but what I have done, I am telling. For spring boot you dont need to keep tomcat explicitly. If you run it boot initialized the embedded tomcat  , so I think we need to configure any setting within .properties or .yml file

Comment: for name if your sever has a public IP or DNS server and your application port is 80 , then your application will be directly accessible from http:domainname.com

Answer (score 0):

Solution is create ROOT.war in the webapp tomcat folder.