# How change web context in spring boot with vaadin?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, wildfly

I have a maven project, using spring boot and vaadin flow. But I can't change the web context when deploy in my server.

I try putting different variables into the file **application.properties**

```
vaadin.urlMapping=/mycontext/*
server.servlet.context-path=/mycontext
server.contextPath=/mycontext
```

Always after deploying the project, it continues showing the context like **my-project-01-SNAPSHOT**

UPDATE

I deploy like a WAR application in a wildfly server.

Comment: There is some information missing in your question. I took one of my Spring Boot apps, and just added these "server.servlet.context-path=/mycontext, 
server.contextPath=/mycontext" to my application.properties, and it worked as it should. I think this is not necessary: "vaadin.urlMapping=/mycontext/*"

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application

Comment: Check point 2. here: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-change-context-path/

Comment: the Vaadin URL-Mapping is also relative to the context path

Comment: I read all this you mentioned and that's the problem. The context doesn't change. For that reason, I posted in the question I using vaadin, for it's a problem compatibility with the framework.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, the problem occurs because I deploy like a WAR application into my wildfly. I fixed it adding to my project a **/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml** file

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/mycontext</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```