# Spring boot application start without proper application name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When running

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

current spring boot application can open in the browser with current URL

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

but not

```
http://localhost:8080/AppName
```

So even in Swagger the APIs has to retrieve like this

```
http://localhost:8080/api/swagger.json
```

instead of this

```
http://localhost:8080/AppName/api/swagger.json
```

So how to add the `AppName` in the context? Easy in the old days where web.xml is xml based, in java based config I have add

```
spring.application.name=AppName
```

but still don't resolve the issue.

Comment: It's using embeded tomcat, thus it has its own port, and no need the sub appname, you can config reversed proxy in nginx, and map an app name to the port.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add context path to Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So how to add the AppName in the context?

Spring Boot, by default, serves content on the root context path (“/”), But we can change it in different ways.
1) Using application.properties / yml

```
   For Boot 1.x, the property is server.context-path=/AppName
   For Boot 2.x, the property is server.servlet.context-path=/AppName
```

2) Using Java system property

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/AppName");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

3) Using OS Environment Variable
   On Linux:- `$ export SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH=/AppName`
   On Windows:- `set SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH=/AppName`

4) Using Command Line Arguments

```
$ java -jar app.jar --server.servlet.context-path=/AppName
```

5) Using Java Config

With Spring Boot 2, we can use `WebServerFactoryCustomizer`:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory>
  webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/AppName");
}
```

With Spring Boot 1, we can create an instance of `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
  embeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
    return container -> container.setContextPath("/AppName");
}
```

**Note:-** Priority order in descending order, which Spring Boot uses to select the effective configuration:

Java Config
Command Line Arguments
Java System Properties
OS Environment Variables
application.properties in Current Directory
application.properties in the classpath (src/main/resources or the packaged jar file)

Comment: I've used both 1 and 2 option but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the context path

- Spring Boot 1.x: `server.contextPath=/AppName`
- Spring Boot 2.x: `server.servlet.contextPath=/AppName`

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
`server.servlet.context-path` for Spring Boot 2.x
`server.context-path` for Spring 1.x
in your application.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your application.properties (works with Spring Boot 1.x):

`server.contextPath=/AppName`

if your version is 2.x, the use the following:

`server.servlet.contextPath=/AppName`