# Spring boot 404 error Not found error in multi module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-restcontroller, multi-module

I'm trying to run my first spring boot multi-module project. 
[image]

by calling from postman http://localhost:8080/test I get 404 Status

This is my Bootstrap POM.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-.0.0.xsd"> <parent>
        <artifactId>gestionactive</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.entreprise</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.entreprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is My Main class in bootstrap module:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import restapi.UserA;

@SpringBootApplication 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.gestionactive.infrastructure.restapi"}) 
@EnableAutoConfiguration public class GestionActiveApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(GestionActiveApplication.class);
    } }
```

infrastructure POM.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>gestionactive</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.entreprise</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>infrastructure</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My REST CONTROLLER (IN INFRASTRUCTURE MODULE)

```
package restapi;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class UserA {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getTest(){
        return "TEST";
    }

}
```

GLOBAL POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>infrastructure</module>
        <module>bootstrap</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.entreprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>gestionactive</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>entreprise actif management tool</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I do not know how to manage Modules dependencies to make this code working

Thank in advance!

Comment: Have you set your spring-boot context path to `test`? Example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application

Comment: I configured my application.yml as follow:
```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /test
```
And I'm having the same 404 error

Comment: hey @adilbouchana, did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and faced by created two config file.
One for the controller to explain to spring which package to look for

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class InfrastructureConfig {
}
```

And one for the application to tell the application the rules of yours modules, as you only have one, the InfrastructureConfig you will have something like

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        InfrastructureConfig.class,
})
public class BootstrapConfig {
}
```

places this two files in their respective module.