# How can I set context path in spring boot jboss/wildfly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, java-war

I know how to set context path in WAR project.
Create a context.xml file in META-INF folder and add the below lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/my-project-path"/>
```

But i don't know how to set in JAR projects without context.xml file.
I had tried the following methods, but not working

```
1) server.servlet.context-path=/my-project-path in application.properties
2) System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/my-project-path");
```

### EDIT

**server.servlet.context-path=/my-project-path** is working in netbeans embeded Tomcat.

But not working in jboss/wildfly

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot do you use?

Comment: Spring Boot version - 2.4.2

Comment: I hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the server.* properties that Spring Boot supports only apply to the configuration of the embedded servlet container (Tomcat).

**Jboss wildfly**

Add your `jboss-web.xml` file in this directory : `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
        <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much