# How to set context root path in spring boot embedded tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, applicationcontext, embedded-tomcat

I want to add my own application name as the prefix. Example: http://localhost:8084/MyApp/some-url. But when I click on some link (href) it redirects me to http://localhost:8084/some-url.
Also I've added server.servlet.context-path=/MyApp in properties file. **Note:** I'm using spring boot 2.5.4v and embedded tomcat 9.0.53v

Comment: I'm currently testing with the same versions and it works fine with `server.servlet.context-path=/MyApp` attached. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application

Comment: @İsmailY. Not working in my case.

Comment: Share your files (application.properties etc.) in your case with us.

Comment: application.properties
`server.servlet.context-path=/MyApp`

Controller:
`@RequestMapping("/some-url")
 public String somePage(Model model) {
  
  model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");

  return "some-page";
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot: 2.7.9 and its embedded tomcat which is above 9.0.0.

I noticed that `server.servlet.contextPath=/my-path` does not work and it picks the executable jar file name which gradle builds. I mean the name of the jar file when we build it (it will get deployed in a openjdk:11-jre-slim container to aws fargate).

This one works for us:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.setContextPath("my-path");
}
```

You may define this bean in any configuration classes.
I know that this one will work with embedded tomcat too but it is more like a deployment time config:

```
java -jar -Dserver.servlet.context-path=/my-path your-jar-file-name.jar
```

Comment: Where is "factory" coming from?

Comment: `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` is a functional interface, so the type we specify in `<>`, will be injected and that is the factory we are seeing here. It allows further customization of the web server. This explanation might help:
```
Strategy interface for customizing web server factories. Any beans of this type will get a callback with the server factory before the server itself is started, so you can set the port, address, error pages etc.
```